# Choosing the right shard key in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, sharding

We are building our first **MongoDB** and currently we are trying to choose the right shard key.

Each document in our main collection contain around `40 voice call` related fields and the main field that we use in queries is the UserId field. This is why we are thinking about compound shard key of `userid` and `CallStartTime`.

They are not sure regarding the second field since `StartTime` is always advancing and one might argue that it is not random enough. This led us to consider replace it with `UserId` and `hashed _id` (mongo internal id after hash).

Is the first option is ok or do we better use the latter?

Comment: You could use hashed indexes on that: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-clusters/#sharding-hashed-sharding

Comment: Also, this feels more like a system administration question...

Comment: i also considered hash keys: "...replace it with UserId + hashed _id (mongo internal id after hash)..."

Answer (score 1):

Consider the recommendations in the documentation here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-internals/#shard-keys

Or, if there is no natural choice, consider using a hashed shard key (mongodb 2.4+)
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-hashed-shard-key

Answer (score 0):

What sort of queries are you performing? What are the access patterns.

Ideally you want a key with good cardinality, write scaling and query isolation.

In your examples above you would need to know the callstarttime or hash to avoid scatter-gather operations.

Comment: not really - to avoid scatter-gather  you need to have at least the primary key and it is ok.

Comment: Most of our queries are userid based. we also may have queries that will use the last update time hence we are considering our shard key to be userid + last update time.